# Python lxml xpath returns no output

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I try to scrape a specific element on a website using lxml in Python. Below you can find my code, but there is no output.

```
    from lxml import html

    webpage = 'http://www.funda.nl/koop/heel-nederland/'
    page = requests.get(webpage)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

    content = '//*[@id="content"]/form/div[2]/div[5]/div/a[8]/text()'
    content = str(tree.xpath(content))
    print content
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that website you are attempting to scrap does not like to be scrapped. They utilize various techniques to detect if request comes from legitimate user or from bot and block access if they think it comes from bot. That's why your xpath does not find anything and that's why you should reconsider whatever you are doing.

If you decide that you want to continue, then the simplest way of fooling this particular website seems to be adding cookies to your requests.

First, obtain cookie string using you real browser:

1. Open new tab
2. Open developers tools
3. Go to "Network" tab in developer tools
4. If network tab is empty, refresh page
5. Find request to `heel-nederland/` and click it
6. In Request Headers, you will find cookie string - it is quite long and contains many seemingly-random characters. Copy it

Then, modify your program to use these cookies:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

webpage = 'http://www.funda.nl/koop/heel-nederland/'
headers = {
        'Cookie': '<string copied from browser>'
        }
page = requests.get(webpage, headers=headers)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

selector = '//*[@id="content"]/form/div[2]/div[5]/div/a[8]/text()'
content = str(tree.xpath(selector))
print content
```